# How to display result of searchbar list in another xaml?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I would like to show the search results in another xml page. As in this scheme:
[image]

the page where the searchbar is present has the following xml's code:

```
 <SearchBar SearchButtonPressed="SearchBar_SearchButtonPressed"
```

while the code c# is:

```
 public partial class FriendsPage : ContentPage
{
    public FriendsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);
    }

    private void SearchBar_SearchButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var search = sender as SearchBar;
        this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SearchBarFriends(search.Text), true);
    }
}
```

the **SearchBarFriends** page should show a simple list and I have structured it as follows
C# code:

```
public partial class SearchBarFriends : ContentPage
{
    public SearchBarFriends()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public SearchBarFriends(String key)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        searchBar.Text = key;
        Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);

        BindingContext = new MyListViewModelUser();
    }

    async void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        DbConnectionClass db = new DbConnectionClass();
        User u = e.Item as User;
        int id = db.QueryId("SELECT id FROM thewishlist.user WHERE nome='" + u.nome + "'OR cognome='" + u.cognome +"'");

        var friendsCorrenteJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(u);
        App.Current.Properties["friends"] = friendsCorrenteJson;
        await App.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProfileFriend(u));

        db.CloseConnection();

    }

    //clicked on searchbar
    void Handle_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var search = sender as SearchBar;
        var _container = BindingContext as MyListViewModelUser;
        EmployeeListView.BeginRefresh();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewTextValue))
            EmployeeListView.ItemsSource = _container.MyListCollector;
        else
        {
            EmployeeListView.ItemsSource = _container.MyListCollector.Where(
                u => u.nome.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower()) || u.cognome.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower()));
        }
        EmployeeListView.EndRefresh();
    }
}
```

}

The XML has the following searchbar followed by a simple ScrollView showing the list:

```
<SearchBar x:Name="searchBar" Placeholder="Friends..." FontAttributes="Italic" PlaceholderColor="Silver" TextChanged="Handle_TextChanged" BackgroundColor="#FFFC79" HorizontalOptions="Start"  VerticalOptions="Start" CancelButtonColor="Black"/>
         <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyListCollector}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" x:Name="EmployeeListView" HasUnevenRows="true" ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

but at run time it generates an error, **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**:

```
 EmployeeListView.ItemsSource = _container.MyListCollector.Where(
                u => u.nome.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower()) || u.cognome.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower()));
```

Comment: Which specific line throws the exception?  And which specific element of that line is null?  You need to figure that out before you can fix the problem

Comment: this is the line **EmployeeListView.ItemsSource = _container.MyListCollector.Where(
                u => u.nome.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower()) || u.cognome.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower()));**

Comment: there are about a dozen things in that one line that could be null - which one is it?

Comment: I don't know I don't report the subject, but the whole line

Comment: you need to use the debugger to figure it out.  There's no way we can do it for you.  If you don't know how to use the debugger (you should learn) you could add code to test each individual element for null prior to executing that line.